# Group ans sum from csv beore import

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I have a script to update a google cloud sql db from a csv attached to a mail.

Problem is the csv file is big. I wonder if it is possible to make a calculation on the csv before transferring the data. For ex: 
Select Col5, Col8, Col9, sum(Col11) group by Col5, Col8, Col9 
Then with this data create my SQL statement for the import.

This is my actual code:

```
function writeManyRecords() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('TRUNCATE test_orders');
  stmt.execute();
  conn.commit();

  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:stock_fastmag subject:"Analyse_ventes"');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  attachment.setContentType('text/csv');

 // Is the attachment a CSV file
 if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ";");  
  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO test_orders '
      + '(Vente, Date, Heure, CodeMag, Total) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    stmt.setString(1, data[i][0]);
    stmt.setString(2, data[i][1]);
    stmt.setString(3, data[i][2]);
    stmt.setString(4, data[i][3]);
    stmt.setString(5, data[i][4]);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }


  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
  }
  conn.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms for %s rows.', end - start, batch.length);
```

Comment: Possible solution: 1.Drive API to convert csv to googleSheets, then 2. get data from gsheet using google query `tq` url https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage You may also try this without converting to gSheet.

Comment: @TheMaster This is basically what I was doing before. I was importing the data in one sheet then another sheet with a query then the script to update the DB. Thing is that the first table is huge that's why I was wondering if I could directly modify se csv (which is sent from an ERP) before uploading